# Mail sending, but no variables in mail - cakePHP

Tags: php, email, cakephp-2.2

**Background**

I have a script that sends an email. This email is sent fine. It sends the template, the design is working fine and all the hard coded text is in there.

**Problem**

Although the mail sends fine, all the variables are missing.

**Code**

Here is my email template, `boardroom_email.ctp` in the `APP/View/Emails/html/` folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <table width="800" align="center" bgcolor="#8dc641" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!-- Header Image -->
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold"><h3 align="center">New Boardroom Booking</h3></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding:10px">
          <table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">
                The following Boardroom Booking has been made
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="30%">
                <b>Requested By:</b>
              </td>
              <td width="70%">
                <?php echo $BoardroomBooking['BoardroomBooking']['name'] ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
<!-- File truncated because the rest just repeats the above variable -->
```

Over here is the function in the BoardroomBookingsController that get's called when a record is successfully saved.

```
function _sendNewBoardroomBookingMail($id) {
    $BoardroomBooking = $this->BoardroomBooking->read(null,$id);
    $this->Email->to = array('Person 1 <person1@mycompany.com>', 'Person 2 <person2@mycompany.com>');
    $this->Email->subject = 'A new boardroom booking has been made';
    $this->Email->replyTo = 'no-reply@mycompany.com';
    $this->Email->from = 'My Company Intraweb <no-reply@mycompany.com>';
    $this->Email->template = 'boardroom_email';
    $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
    $this->set('BoardroomBooking', $BoardroomBooking);
    $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
    $this->Email->_debug = true;
    if ($this->Email->send()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Result**

This is what the above code sends me:

[image]

**Question**

Obviously I'm missing something small. I had it working at one stage and can't remember that I changed anything, but now, it sends me an email with no data.

What is it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->set('BoardroomBooking', $BoardroomBooking);` doesn't work in the new `CakeEmailComponent`

You need to use:

```
$this->Email->viewVars(compact('BoardroomBooking'));
//or
$this->Email->viewVars(array('BoardroomBooking' => $BoardroomBooking));
```

Comment: I get an error now: `Call to undefined method EmailComponent::viewVars()`

Comment: You should use [`CakeEmail`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#cakeemail) instead of the `EmailComponent`